# Appending/Concatenating List of Dataframe Series Reduce in Size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

Please help why the number of rows reduce from 525 to 509?

[image]
[image]

I try to concat series of dataframe from reading excel files that has been appended into a list.

Comment: Post your code as text and not as images. Also, can you provide a sample of your spreadsheet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is that "verify_integrity" in pd.concat removing duplicates?